# Powershell xml <title> string

Tags: powershell

I have a directory of xml files  and I want to extract the title for each. I am very new to powershell, and have tried the following.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Get-Content | Select-String -pattern "<title>" -list | Set-Content protid_output.txt
```

An example of the relevant part of the xml files:
   < title> protein name < /title>

This outputs the title tag but not the actual title. How can I go through the directory and output the titles to one file?

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that the all of `<title>this title</title>` is on a SINGLE line, then try:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | % { 
    ((Get-Content .\test.xml) -match "<title>" -replace '<title>' -replace '</title>').Trim()
} | Set-Content protid_output.txt
```

If they are more like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<example>
<title>
protein name
</title>
</example>
```

Then try parsing it to xml-object first(easier to read), but avoid on 10+ MB files. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { 
    $x = [xml](Get-Content $_)
    $x.example.title.Trim()
} | Set-Content protid_output.txt
```

Comment: Your second example is the best method to use. Parsing XML with regexes & string matching is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: +1 alroc, but if you have many files that are 20-30-40MB big, it takes a lot of time. So as long as your 100% sure about the format the files use, string matching would improve the performance. :)

Comment: I think I figured out why my implementation and your first were not working for me apparently it is across multiple lines. The title I want should always be the same line in the file, I used this.
    Get-ChildItem -recurse | Get-Content | Select-Object -Index 4 | Set-Content out.txt

which works perfectly for one file, but it doesn't recurse through the other files in the directory. Any thoughts?

Comment: When you do `Get-ChildItem -recurse | Get-Content` you get an array of all lines from all files. So when you add `| Select-Object -Index 4` you say that you only want the forth line (line from line nr 4.). To avoid mistakes, you should use the 2nd part of my answer instead. But to answer how to fix your solution. Try using `select ..` per file, like this: `Get-ChildItem -recurse | % { Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Index 4 } | Set-Content out.txt`